# #MongoDB How to find the item which start from specific letter

Tags: mongodb

I am trying the tutorial on:

If I want to find the item start with letter 'p', how can I do that?
I've tried

```
 > db.inventory.find( {item: $regex /^p/} )
```

But its not correct

> 2019-04-12T21:31:35.754-0700 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: expected expression, got '^' @(shell):1:34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the braces around `$regex`:

From [regex documenetation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

```js
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/<options> } }
```

In your case:

```js
db.inventory.find( {item: { $regex: /^p/}})
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```js
db.inventory.find( {item: /^p/ } )
```